# .htaccess redirect - Is it secure?

Tags: mod-rewrite, .htaccess, redirect, security

This works; I'm not having trouble, *but* I want to be certain that this is bulletproof.

**I came up with a neat little *`.htaccess` redirect*, but I am not sure if it is secure; do you know?**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^goto/([a-z]+)/?$ /$1/ [R]
</IfModule>
```

I think as long as the server is configured correctly and the files handle authentication autonomously, then it shouldn't be a security issue.
Also, being that the rewrite rule only works with characters a-z and one slash I doubt they could jump around directories by injecting stuff into the URL
I think...

Answer (score 1):

It's actually moot because of the [R] flag.

Because you're sending an *external* redirect it means security shits over to the point when the server receives the rewritten URL. At this point it's just like it would be if someone lifted a URL from a keylogger on your computer. The server should treat the rewritten URL via the new request like there was never a rewrite.

Answer (score 0):

The .htaccess redirect itself is indeed "secure" (unless a severe remotely-exploitable bug is found in mod_rewrite or mod_rewrite-related Apache code).

Let us have a look at a sample request coming in:

1. Apache (mod_rewrite) checks if the rule matches
2. if it does: Apache doesn't do anything else except for sending a redirection header to the browser
3. if it doesn't: Apache processes the request as any other (i.e. starts looking for a matching file, ...)

The only problem I can think of is somehow redirecting the visitor to a file s/he's not expected to see. For example, if Apache is allowed to "follow symlinks", and the rewrite rule points at a symlink to e.g. your /etc/passwd, then Apache will act as instructed and will send your /etc/passwd to the browser. But that is not really a security issue of .htaccess redirect.